# How should the tag [graph-algorithms] be used?

Tags: discussion, tags

How should the tag [graph-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) be used?  In particular, should it be used together with [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), should it be used exclusively of [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory), or does it depend on questions?

Currently, I fail to see any difference between the questions tagged as [graph-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) and the [questions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms+graph-theory) tagged both as [ds.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms) and [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).  Many questions are actually given all of these three tags.

If there is a guideline how to apply these tags to questions about graph algorithms, it is probably better to explain it in tag wiki.

Comment: I suppose you can't make the tag a synonym for [ds.algorithms] + [graph-theory]. So maybe you should just leave it as it is. It's also possible some questions should be tagged [data-structures] and [graph-theory], but not [graph-algorithms]. We should say something about this in the tag wiki.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the comment.  (1) I also suppose that we cannot make a synonym for a combination of tags.  (2) I understand that presumably there are questions which are related to algorithms and graph theory but are not about graph algorithms.  (3) I do not know what to write in tag wikis about which tags to use for questions about graph algorithms.  To be honest, it is tempting to write: “For questions about graph algorithms, people seem to choose arbitrarily to tag them as some or all of [ds.algorithms], [graph-theory] and [graph-algorithms].”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we need the most specific tag relating to the question. So I can easily imagine graph-algorithms being more specific than graph-theory. Also, ds.algorithms is special in that it's an arxiv tag, and we have desired as far as possible to keep at least one arxiv tag for each question. So I'd say the main distinction is between graph-theory and graph.algorithms, and the wiki for graph-theory could say something like

> If your question pertains specifically
>   to algorithms on graphs, you should
>   use the more specific
>   [graph-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms)

and the wiki for graph-algorithms could say something like

> This tag is specifically for
>   algorithms on graphs. For more general
>   graph theory questions, please use
>   [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory)

ds.algorithms itself should emphasize that it's an arxiv tag, with something like

> ds.algorithms is a component of the
>   arxiv cs.ds categorization, and should
>   be used on all questions that relate
>   to the design and analysis of
>   algorithms. While the design and
>   analysis of data-structures also
>   includes algorithms, the more specific
>   [ds.data-structures](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.data-structures) should be
>   used for those questions. For
>   algorithms in computational geometry
>   for example (which has its own
>   top-level tag [cg.comp-geom](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cg.comp-geom),
>   algorithmic questions should use both
>   ds.algorithms and cg.comp-geom.

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me.  If there are no other opinions in a while, I can edit the tag wikis.  Of course anyone interested and having enough rep can go ahead.