# Do we need the tag graph-algorithms?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should the tag [graph-algorithms] be used?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/680/how-should-the-tag-graph-algorithms-be-used)

Do we really need the [graph-algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-algorithms) tag? Isn't [ds.algortihms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algortihms) and [graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) sufficient?

Note:

Currently there are 147 questions tagged with it, two third of them also have the tags reffed above.
From the remaining 43 questions, 14 are tagged with [cc.complexity-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory) and are not about algorithms but complexity of graph problems (e.g. $\mathsf{NP\text{-}hardness}$). 
The remaining 29 questions also seem to mostly fall in [ds.algorithms](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms)+[graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory) and few are again not algorithmic questions and should be tagged as [cc.complexity-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cc.complexity-theory)+[graph-theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).

Comment: @suresh, it has been a while since that question and I forgot about it, thanks. :)